# Papyrus: Error exporting diagram as an image file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, papyrus

This problem refers to an Eclipse Kepler instance running on Ubuntu 12.04. I have a Use Case diagram that I need to include in a document as an image file. I right click on the *.di* file, select ***Export All Diagrams...*** and then select *PDF* as the file format. In return I get an error window with the following:

> ExportAll report
>
> Reason: 
>   Generation failed for some tests

In the error log an exception is filed:

> **Message:** 
>   error during generation of diagram NewDiagram in resource platform:/resource/EMS-iGUESS_Components/models/UseCasesNew.notation
>
> **Exception Stack Trace:** 
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: negative width     at java.awt.BasicStroke.(BasicStroke.java:181)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.render.awt.internal.graphics.GraphicsToGraphics2DAdaptor.createStroke(GraphicsToGraphics2DAdaptor.java:1544)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.render.awt.internal.graphics.GraphicsToGraphics2DAdaptor.drawPolygon(GraphicsToGraphics2DAdaptor.java:633)
>     at org.eclipse.draw2d.Graphics.drawPolygon(Graphics.java:293)   at
>   org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.internal.graphics.ScaledGraphics.drawPolygon(ScaledGraphics.java:356)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.usecase.draw2d.StickMan.outlineShape(StickMan.java:62)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.usecase.draw2d.ShadowShape.outlineShape(ShadowShape.java:134)
>     at org.eclipse.draw2d.Shape.paintOutline(Shape.java:175)    at
>   org.eclipse.draw2d.Shape.paintFigure(Shape.java:147)  at
>   org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.usecase.draw2d.ShadowShape.paint(ShadowShape.java:109)
>     at org.eclipse.draw2d.Figure.paintChildren(Figure.java:1167)    at
>   org.eclipse.draw2d.Figure.paintClientArea(Figure.java:1202)   at
>   org.eclipse.draw2d.Figure.paint(Figure.java:1117)     at
>   org.eclipse.draw2d.Figure.paintChildren(Figure.java:1167)     at
>   org.eclipse.draw2d.Figure.paintClientArea(Figure.java:1202)   at
>   org.eclipse.draw2d.Figure.paint(Figure.java:1117)     at
>   org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.render.clipboard.DiagramGenerator.paintFigure(DiagramGenerator.java:373)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.render.clipboard.DiagramGenerator.renderToGraphics(DiagramGenerator.java:226)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.render.clipboard.DiagramGenerator.createSWTImageDescriptorForParts(DiagramGenerator.java:721)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.render.util.CopyToImageUtil.copyToImage(CopyToImageUtil.java:376)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.render.util.CopyToImageUtil.copyToImage(CopyToImageUtil.java:305)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.render.util.CopyToImageUtil.copyToImage(CopyToImageUtil.java:123)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.export.ExportAllDiagrams.exportDiagram(ExportAllDiagrams.java:357)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.export.ExportAllDiagrams.access$3(ExportAllDiagrams.java:354)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.export.ExportAllDiagrams$6.run(ExportAllDiagrams.java:336)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:164)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:158)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3717)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3366)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
>
> **Session Data:**
>  
>   eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700 
> java.version=1.6.0_26 
> java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. BootLoader
>   constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB Framework
>   arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
>   Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

What is wrong here? How can I export the diagram as an image file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that some elements (like Actors, ReceiveSignal) didn't accept a negative value for the Line width field. On these elements, you can replace the "-1" value by "1" in ***Properties***  / ***Appearance*** / ***Line width field***.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Export it as an SVG file. You can view them in a browser and convert them to other formats later